# Python: simple ctypes dll load yields error

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, windowserror

I created the MathFuncsDll.dll from [MSDN DLL example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and running the calling .cpp worked fine. Now, trying to load this in IPython with ctypes like

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.WinDLL('MathFuncsDll.dll')
```

being in the correct folder yields

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Similarly in Python shell this yields

```
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

What should I change? Hm, it might be Win 7 64bit vs. some 32bit dll or something right? I'll check later when I've time again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ctypes` doesn't work with C++, which the MathFuncsDLL example is written in.

Instead, write in C, or at least export a "C" interface:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

__declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Also note that the calling convention defaults to `__cdecl`, so use `CDLL` instead of `WinDLL` (which uses `__stdcall` calling convention):

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> dll=ctypes.CDLL('server')
>>> dll.Add.restype = ctypes.c_double
>>> dll.Add.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double,ctypes.c_double]
>>> dll.Add(1.5,2.7)
4.2
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't differentiate between C and C++ at all when trying to load a DLL. So C, C++ and C# have to be considered separately, as well as plain, .Net and maybe other flavors? That is ctypes for C, maybe Boost for C++ and pythonnet for .Net/C# DLLs, right?

Comment: Yes, there are different solutions for each.  FYI, on StackOverflow if an answer is useful to you, up vote and/or accept it as the answer to your question using the arrows/check on the left of the answer.

Comment: Ah, thank you for all your advice; I didn't know how to acknowledge your answer. I couldn't vote it up, my reputation is too low. I assume I can only provide a C interface to a C++ DLL if I have the source code. Or is this also possible for 3rd party DLLs the source code of which I do not have access to?

Comment: I've used SWIG to interface to a C++ DLL.  It can get complicated for more than simple object interfaces, but is very powerful.  It basically writes a C interface layer and a python proxy library that makes it look like C++ objects again.