# could not load c++ DLL in python

Tags: c++, python, dll

I am trying to use a C++ `.dll` in Python, but I can't even load it. I am trying the following python code to load it:

```
from ctypes import cdll
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('SORT_DLL.dll')
```

But when I try to run this I get:

```
D:\...\src\SORT_DLL\Debug>UseDll.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\...\src\SORT_DLL\Debug\UseDll.py", line 2, in
 <module>
    mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary('SORT_DLL.dll')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 ist keine zulõssige Win32-Anwendung
```

The last sentence means "%1 is not a valid Win32 application" in English.

I already looked it up at http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes , but this didn't lead to a solution for my problem.

Comment: First, is it actually a `cdll` rather than a `windll`? Second, as the documentation says, you're not supposed to add the `.dll` suffix on Windows.

Comment: Also, one good way to debug ctypes problems loading libraries is to break the steps up explicitly. First try to use the native Win32 `LoadLibrary` (if you've got PyWin32, that's the easiest way; if not, you can `ctypes` the system DLL, I think it's user32, or you can use the undocumented wrapper in `_ctypes.LoadLibrary`) and see if you can get a handle. Then you can try to create a `CDLL` instance by calling the constructor with the explicit handle and see what happens. If the first step works but the second fails, try some explicit `GetProcAddress` calls with the handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you have an incompatible version of Python installed or the DLL was compiled using the wrong settings. The DLL and the Python interpreter both have to be either 32 or 64 Bit.

Comment: Thanks. Although i have compiled the DLL for 64bit and had the Python 64bit version installed, it didn't work. Now i have the 32bit version of Python installed and everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10163943/953887

"ctypes doesn't work with C++, which the [DLL] example is written in."