# Unable to load C++ dll in python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have a **C++** **dll** which I'm trying to use it in **Python**,

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\TestDll.dll")
```

until now there are no errors, system seem to be doing what I wanted, but when I try to access `mydll`, the Intellisence in the Python IDLE shows the following,

[image]

from the above pic, it's clear that the intellisence doesn't show up any available functions of the dll, but when I checked the same TestDll.dll with `dumpbin /EXPORTS TestDll.dll` it has 45 functions, but none of those functions are available with python.

[image]

**Please Note**: There are several questions on this topic, I tried the following suggestions but no use,

- [incompatible version of Python installed or the DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13268880/1463551) [TestDll.dll & Python both are 32 bit versions]
- [I think ctypes is the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252473/1463551) [Same Issue, cant see any functions, but loads the dll]

Now my question is how do I load all the available functions(as shown by dumpbin)?

**Edit 1**

Based on [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) suggestion, I was able to make some progress. The `TestDll.dll` comes along with a header file `TestDll.h`(my bad I missed this file earlier), from which I could see the available Exported Functions.

**`TestDll.h:`**

```
_stdcall Function1 (const char* prtFileString, cont char* prtDescrip, struct FileParams* ptrParsms);

struct FileParams
{
  float val1;
  void* pMarker;
};
```

now I've tried the following,

```
>>> mydll = CDLL("c:\\TestDll.dll")
>>> Function1 = mydll.Function1
>>> Function1.restype = c_int
```

until now it's fine, but when I try to define the **argTypes**, not sure how to do it for structs?

```
>>> Function1.argtypes = (c_char_c, c_char_c, ???)
```

any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have C-wrappers around your C++ functions? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163832/python-simple-ctypes-dll-load-yields-error/10163943#10163943

Comment: Not sure if that's the case

Comment: Then you probably don't -- ctypes only works with C. You have to go through some extra steps to use C++.

Comment: yeah I was wrong & I thought ctypes will be able to import all dll's no matter whether it's c or c++, anyways thanks.

Comment: Are the symbol names mangled? If not they were compiled `extern "C"`.

Comment: ctypes won't parse PE image exports as dumpbin does (nor other platforms such as Linux ELF). Load the DLL with `mydll = CDLL("TestDll")`. To instantiate a `_CFuncPtr`, get an exported name as an attribute, e.g. `foo = mydll.foo`, and define the prototype via `foo.restype` and `foo.argtypes`. Or call a prototype (`_CFuncPtr` subclass) with a tuple of a name and lib, e.g. `foo = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_char_p)(('foo', mydll))`. On Windows this is implemented via [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @eryksun, thanks for the responce, I dont think the symbol names where mangled, `dumpbin` shows all the names but not sure how they've compiled. As per the suggestion I'm able to load the dll `mydll = CDLL("TestDll")`, but unable to instantiate functions. could you show me an example please?

Comment: Here's an example. `msvc = CDLL('msvcr100');` `atoi = msvc.atoi; atoi.restype = c_int; atoi.argtypes = (c_char_p,)`. Or instantiate a prototype: `atoi = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_char_p)(('atoi', msvc))`. Either way, `assert atoi(b'123') == 123`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your header, here's a dummy C file (for Windows) that can be used to test a `ctypes` wrapper.  You mentioned C++ but the example was a C interface, which is a good thing because `ctypes` works with C functions not C++.

#### x.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct FileParams
{
  float val1;
  void* pMarker;
};

__declspec(dllexport) _stdcall Function1 (const char* prtFileString, const char* prtDescrip, struct FileParams* ptrParsms)
{
    printf("%s\n%s\n%f %p\n",prtFileString,prtDescrip,ptrParsms->val1,ptrParsms->pMarker);
}
```

Here's the `ctypes` wrapper.  Note that `ctypes` does not inspect the DLL and automatically load all the functions.  You have to declare the functions, parameters and return values yourself.  See [ctypes:structures and unions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) for the `Structure` syntax.

Also note that for a DLL with `_stdcall` functions use `WinDLL` instead of `CDLL`.

#### x.py

```
#!python3
import ctypes

class FileParams(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('val1',ctypes.c_float),
                ('pMarker',ctypes.c_void_p)]

    x = ctypes.WinDLL('x')
    x.Function1.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.POINTER(FileParams)]
    x.Function1.restype = ctypes.c_int
    
    fp = FileParams(1.234,None)
    x.Function1(b'abc',b'def',ctypes.byref(fp))
```

And the output:

```
abc
def
1.234000 0000000000000000
```